# presentation for a nilpotent group associated to the square of a coxeter element

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, kac-moody-algebras

This question is related to one asked earlier about inductive presentations of unipotent radicals in Kac-Moody groups.

Let $\Gamma$ be a *coxeter diagram* --- i.e. an unoriented graph with $r$ vertices whose edges are labeled by the integer weights $\big\{3,4,6 \big\}$. Let $\vec{\Gamma}$ be a directed version of $\Gamma$ where each edge with weight $4$ or $6$ is assigned an orientation. Let $W$ and $G$ respectively denote the coxeter group and the Kac-Moody group associated to $\Gamma$ and $\vec{\Gamma}$; in addition choose an opposing pair of Borel subgroups $B_{\pm}$ of $G$ and let $N_{\pm}$ denote the corresponding unipotent radicals.
Given $w \in W$ let $\dot{w}$ denote a lifting of $w$ to $G$ and 
consider the subgroup $N(w) := N \cap \big( \dot{w} \big)^{-1} N_{-} \big( \dot{w} \big)$ of $N$; it is a finite dimensional nilpotent group which,
as a variety, is isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}^{l(w)}$ where $l(w)$ is the length
of $w$.

**Question** Let $c = \sigma_1 \dots \sigma_r$ be a choice of coxeter element of $W$ and consider $N\big(c^2 \big)$. Is there way to read off 
a presentation of this group from $\Gamma$; in a manner analagous 
to the Chevalley presentation of $N$ (but with added relations) ?

regards,
A. Leverkühn

p.s. This question only becomes interesting in the case that $l \big(c^2 \big) = 2 \cdot l(c)$ otherwise $N \big( c^2 \big)$ will be abelian. For example type $\Gamma = A_r$ is **not** interesting
while type $\Gamma = D_r$ for $r \geq 4$ is. Is it possible that $N \big( c^2 \big) \cong \ N\big( c \big) \rtimes N \big( c \big)$ when this length condition is satisfied ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your main question but response to your post script remark. In general it is **not** the case that $N \big(c^2 \big) \cong
N(c) \rtimes N(c)$. Consider the case of $\vec{\Gamma} = B_2$. The Kac-Moody group in this case is the symplectic group $\text{Sp}_{4}\big( \Bbb{C} \big)$; namely all $4 \times 4$ invertible complex matrices $g$ for which

\begin{equation}  g^T \,  \left(  \begin{array}{r|c}
\Bbb{O} & \dot{w}   \\
\hline 
-\dot{w} &  \Bbb{O} \\
\end{array}
\right) \, g \ = \  \left( \begin{array}{r|c}
\Bbb{O} & \dot{w}   \\ 
\hline  
-\dot{w} &  \Bbb{O} \\
\end{array} \right) \end{equation}

where $\dot{w}$ is the $2 \times 2$ permutation matrix of the transposition $w = \big(1  \, 2 \big)$ in $S_2$. The corresponding unipotent radical $N$ can be expressed as the group of all $4 \times 4$ matrices $g$ possessing a block-decomposition of the form

\begin{equation} \left(
\begin{array}{cc|cr}
1 &a &ax + z &az + y \\
0 &1 &x &z \\  
\hline  
0 &0 &1 &-a \\
0 &0 &0 &1
\end{array}
\right) \end{equation}

for any choice or complex parameters $a$, $x$, $y$, and $z$. The square-coxeter subgroup $N \big(c^2 \big)$ in this case coincides with $N$.
On the other hand $N(c)$ will be the two-dimensional subgroup consisting of all $4 \times 4$ matrices with block-form

\begin{equation} \left(
\begin{array}{cc|cr}
1 &0 &z &0\\
0 &1 &x &z \\  
\hline  
0 &0 &1 &0 \\
0 &0 &0 &1
\end{array} \right)
\end{equation}

One can check that $N(c)$ is **not** normal in $N$ which immediately rules out your conjecture. **However** the subgroup $H$ consisting of matrices of the form

\begin{equation} \left(
\begin{array}{cc|cr}
1 &0 &z &y \\
0 &1 &x &z \\  
\hline  
0 &0 &1 &0 \\
0 &0 &0 &1
\end{array}
\right) \end{equation}

is normal in $N$ and indeed there is a semi-direct product decomposition $N \cong H \rtimes \Bbb{C}$ where we view $\Bbb{C}$ as an additive group; which
is related to a question you raised in another posting.

yours, Ines